# ViewController doesn't look properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a ViewController that looks like this:

[image]

but when i run it, it looks like this:

[image]

Heres some code in the ViewController:

```
    @IBAction func derecourtButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func myburghButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func edmondsonButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func healyButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func bormansButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func jackwaysButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }

    @IBAction func horrackButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func mchughButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func youngButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func mitchellButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func testerButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func parrButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func holdenButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

    }
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: You should use Auto Layout to set some constraints on the view.

Comment: Have you looked into using a `UITableViewController` to display that number of items to the user?

Comment: Doubt it has anything to do with code. Are you using autolayout? If yes, Show us the constraints. If no, do it.

Comment: Also, As Magnas said, you will profit from using UITableView instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code, it is in the .xib file. There is no enough space for all the views that you have implemented. You have to build all the views setting constraints. So you can say that something has % of height and % of width of the container or of another element. Or to set them in the middle or wherever you want using % of sizes or px.

What you need is called autolayout & constraints.

[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) you have 2 tutorials of Raywenderlich.

As I am seeing you have a scrollview here you have a tutorial of how using a scrollview too!

However, first you have to [learn about constraints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjTS9fyWqdg), they are too important.